# Having issues updating Rails application with Aptana Studio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sftp, aptana

I created a test Rails application through Digital Ocean (I don't know if you'll need my application's IP address, I'm not sure whether or not posting it on here will create security issues.)

I wanted to being to develop and test my Rails application in a live server, so I connected to it through SFTP with Aptana Studio.

I connect to my Rails application by clicking on Window->Show View->Remote and then connecting to my SFTP server.

I'm able to see my Rails install in Aptana, so I go to edit one of the views just to make sure my connection is working.

I go to app/views/layouts/application.html.erb (the one automatically generated by Digital Ocean's 1-click Rails installer), and I change the `<title>` tag from "RailsProject" to "Test", then right-click the file in explorer and click "Upload".

When I load up my live server in a web browser, the changes have not taken effect.

When I connect to my server SFTP through FileZilla and look at my files that way, I can see the changes I've made are on the server (I've edited both layouts/application.html.erb and home/index.html.erb), but the changes are not showing up on my test application when I open it in a browser.

Now, I'm new to both Rails and Aptana (though I'm familiar with Ruby, HTML/CSS, and JavaScript), so it's definitely possible there's a step I missed. But can anyone help me out?

Let me know if there is more info required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restart my Unicorn server. I went into the Terminal while connected to my application and typed:

```
service unicorn restart
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!